# CPU overload when writing from excel to CSV ( Ruby script)

Tags: ruby, cpu-usage, export-to-csv

I want to data from bunch of excel files to a CSV format file.

The script looks something like this:

```
CSV.open("summary_#{SITE}.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ['ID', 'Username', 'Price', 'Date', 'link', 'Retail price', 'Product name']
  Dir.glob("../data/#{SITE}*") do |file|
    cursor_row = 5
    cursor_column = 9
    data_sheet = Spreadsheet.open("#{file}").worksheet 0
    puts "writing from #{file}"
    while data_sheet[4, cursor_column] do 
      while data_sheet[cursor_row, cursor_column] do 
        #add data to a csv row and add csv_row to file
        cursor_row += 1
      end
      cursor_row = 5
      cursor_column += 4
    end
  end
end
```

It seems to be running fine and doing everything correctly. But the problems start when there are multiple files that need to be run in one go.

As far as I've tracked the problem, it seems that the script keeps all excel files, that have already been completed in the CPU memory and every next file seems to be running slower and slower up to the point where around the 8th file 1x4 cell set, it seems, is taking around a second, which is extremely frustrating given that each file contains 10000+ of these sets.

I wasn't successful in finding how exactly can I dump an excel file from the memory once the `data_sheet` variable takes on a new file.

I'm running:

MRI Ruby: 2.2.2
Mac OS X El capitan

using:
"spreadsheet" gem

Any help will be appreciated or any guidance where to look up File reading/writing optimisation with ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually calling Garbage Collection... I think that might get rid of the Spreadsheet objects.

```
data_sheet = nil
GC.start
data_sheet = Spreadsheet.open("#{file}").worksheet 0
```

Comment: Doesn't help. It still keeps the excel files open even after they are done